# html error while accessing pom/jar files in nexus 3 proxy repository

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3, maven-repository

I have upgraded my Nexus Repository to the latest version (3.22.0-02), but I get the following error message when i try to read/download some of the artifacts not available (like this `https://mynexus/repository/ext-thirdparty-maven2-proxy-releases/com/myorg/my_artifact/1.0/my_artifact-1.0.pom`)

In case artifacts are not available it should simply return 404 error codes rather than badly formatted pom.xml .

> Our apologies This website is unavailable at the moment. We are
> working on a solution to make the website available again as soon as
> possible.
>
> We kindly request that you check back shortly to resume your activity.
> Our sincere apologies for the inconvenience.
>
> Onze excuses Deze website is momenteel niet beschikbaar. Wij werken
> aan een oplossing om de website zo snel mogelijk weer beschikbaar te
> maken.
>
> Wij verzoeken u vriendelijk om deze website later opnieuw te bezoeken.
> Onze welgemeende excuses voor het ongemak.

Content type validation configuration for this proxy repository

[image: content type validation configuration for this proxy repo]

Comment: Latest NXRM3 version is 3.29.  But anyway, do you get an error hitting that in the proxy site directly?  NXRM3 doesn't contain that error message so likely something else is returning it to your browser.  Maybe it's the proxy itself?  Also, the fact you said "some" makes me think NXRM is working right.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Error message I posted above is from browser; when we try to access artifact link from browser we encounter this error. But in all such scenarios, nexus returning corrupted files instead of 404 error code, during build (all our builds are maven builds in Jenkins) and builds are failing.

I used "some" in the context that I have not tested all missing artifacts but for the ones I tested I encounter the issue. I reckon if the status of missing artifact was cached before upgrade, reference to such artifacts is giving the error. I cleared cache & tested but no help.

Comment: I see.  And you tried hitting the proxy directly bypassing NXRM?  e.g. http:mavencentral/artifact vs http:nxrmurl/artifact? (for maven)